# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme 'gs' not implemented

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, conda

I followed the example of TensorFlow example workflows and I got the error when excute the code as belows:

```
print('Found Cloud Storage bucket.' if tf.io.gfile.exists(address)
      else 'Output Cloud Storage bucket does not exist.')'
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\memor\Anaconda3\envs\ee\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-04106e6686a2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/1_Database/2_Research/17_GEE/Sential_water/test.py', wdir='D:/1_Database/2_Research/17_GEE/Sential_water')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.5\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.5\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/1_Database/2_Research/17_GEE/Sential_water/test.py", line 93, in <module>
    print('Found Cloud Storage bucket.' if tf.io.gfile.exists(address)
  File "C:\Users\memor\Anaconda3\envs\ee\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 280, in file_exists_v2
    pywrap_tensorflow.FileExists(compat.as_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme 'gs' not implemented
```

OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Windows 10

environment: conda

platform: Pycharm

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): pip install tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0

TensorFlow version (use command below): 2.1.0

Tensorboard version: 2.1.1

Python version: 3.7.6

The example link is https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/TF_demo1_keras.ipynb

Comment: The address is:
`address = 'gs://' + outputBucket`